# Variables in 'if' tests in bash

Tags: bash

I want to check if `~/tost1` file exists, using variable $i, which is equal to `~/tost1`. If statement does not work with the variable. Is there any way to fix it?

```
i=~/tost1
$ echo $i
~/tost1
$ if [ -e ${i} ]; then echo "file exists"; fi

$ if [ -e ~/tost1 ]; then echo "file exists"; fi
file exists
```

Comment: what does `echo $i` give you, is it `~/tost1`? If so then that's wrong as it should be `/home/$USER/path/to/tost1`

Comment: Try `if [ -e ${i} ]; then echo "file exists";else echo "file does not exist";fi` and test both when the file exists and when it does not exist. (It works for me, when the file exists.)

Comment: What version of Bash are you using, and what version of Ubuntu? Cause these commands work fine for me on Bash 4.3.11, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @wjandrea, I use bash 4.3-14ubuntu1.2, and it works too. *@Josef Klimuk*, Which version of bash are you using (or are you using another shell?)

Comment: Voting to close as OP mentioned in a comment he's using Termux on Android. OP, please ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://android.stackexchange.com instead. Also -1 cause I've already told you Termux is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in 16.04 LTS, when run from the command line in a terminal window,

```
$ i=~/tost1
$ echo "$i"
/home/sudodus/tost1

$ touch ~/tost1
$ if [ -e ${i} ]; then echo "file exists";else echo "file does not exist";fi
file exists
```

But it is a good idea to use `$HOME` instead of tilde, particularly if you intend to make a shellscript with the commands that you test interactively, so start with

```
$ i="$HOME"/tost1
$ touch ~/tost1
$ if [ -e "${i}" ]; then echo "file exists";else echo "file does not exist";fi
file exists
```

It is a good habit to double-quote variables, if you want to avoid unpleasant surprises. (There are a few exceptions.)

Comment: Sudodus. First worked for me, but only in CL, not as shell script. In CL the result was: 'file exists'; running the same as a script - 'file does not exists'.

Comment: I'm using bash temporally in termux app. It seems to behave differently, than 'regular' bash.

Comment: I see. Some shell features are 'more standard' and some features are 'less standard'. I'm glad we could find out why you had this problem, and how it could be solved :-)

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE**: OP stated in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973617/variables-in-if-tests-in-bash/973624#comment1561180_973628) "I'm using bash temporally in termux app. It seems to behave differently, than 'regular' bash." This explains the unusual behavior.

According to `bash 4.3` manual used in Ubuntu 16.04:

> Each variable assignment is checked for unquoted tilde-prefixes immediately following a : or the first =.  In these cases,  tilde  expanion  is  also  performed.

In your specific case, tilde is treated as literal character, and your `[` is looking for file in directory that is literally supposed to be called `~`. That's why it fails.

Use environment variable `$HOME` instead, i.e. `$HOME/tost1`.

Comment: Alternatively use `i=$(realpath ~/tost1)` or `i=$(readlink -m ~/tost1)`. The last one works even if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @dessert yep, ok approach as well, or just echo it instead.

Comment: I upvoted this, then realized, wait, the assignment actually work for me. `i=~/tost1; echo "$i"` returns `/home/wja/tost1`.

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, you're right.  I've double checked with the manual, it's indeed performed in *unquoted* assignments, apparently. So the issue is with OP's shell.